# BCDEdit: RecoverySequence is all zeros. Can't Enable WinRE

Tags: windows-10, recovery, bcdedit

I'm having trouble enabling the Recovery Environment for my virtual W10 after making some changes in the BCD store. W10 will still boot, I just can't enable WinRE.

BCDEdit shows that the RecoverySequence is {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, which I'm sure is part of the problem, though I'm not sure how to rectify it.

Oddly, if I run *Reagentc /enable* twice, (1st time fails with "Unable to update Boot Configuration Data.", 2nd time is always successful, though */info* still shows it's disabled) I can repeat this pattern multiple times and the results are always the same: failed, successful, failed, successful, etc., and Reagentc always shows RE is disabled)

If I could just fix the RecoverySequence, I think the issue would resolve itself, unless something else is causing the RecoverySequence to show all zeros.

I probably could delete the BCD and start from scratch to resolve the issue, but I'm trying to learn more about BCDEdit by challenging myself, so would really like to known what likely caused this, and possibly fix it without creating a new store.

**Reagentc /info**

```
Windows RE status:         Disabled
Windows RE location:
Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Recovery image location:
Recovery image index:      0
Custom image location:
Custom image index:        0
```

**BCDEdit -enum -v**

```
 Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  boot
default                 {35870cb9-ff2b-11ed-be42-c075c4fe2d22}
displayorder            {35870cb9-ff2b-11ed-be42-c075c4fe2d22}
timeout                 10
displaybootmenu         Yes


Windows Boot Loader  
-------------------  
identifier              {35870cb9-ff2b-11ed-be42-c075c4fe2d22}  
device                  partition=C:  
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi  
description             W10-Test
recoverysequence        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {abda1fe7-ff32-11ed-be43-806e6f6e6963}
bootmenupolicy          Legacy
```

Comment: What is your VM App? With VMware Workstation, Hyper-V Workstation, or Virtual Box, you would not, so far as I know, recover the guest with BDedit. Use backups instead.

Comment: What changes did you make before this behavior surfaced. Be specific as possible by editing your question

Comment: I created a new BCD store as I had previously done successfully including a working WinRE, though this second time I did it, I noticed RE was not working, and the RecoverySequence was all zeros for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do to reset the whole BCD store:
Windows PE, use a boot disk.

```
diskpart
list volume
select volume 1 (or whichever system partition is)
format fs=fat32 quick label=SYSTEM
active (if mbr only and not efi partition)
assign letter S
select volume 2 (example number --for hidden recovery volume)
assign letter r
list volume (make sure partitions are normal)
exit
```

Now run:

```
bcdboot (windows partition like c:\windows) /s S: /f **BIOS**/**UEFI** 

(bcdboot c:\windows /s s: /f UEFI ---for UEFI /f BIOS --- for BIOS)

**"Boot Files Successfully Created!"**

dir R:\ /A
```

Does it show "Recovery" folder? Maybe Windows RE is on Windows partition? `dir /a C:\Recovery /a` should show Recovery folder.

If it is there skip this next solution:

```
dir /a C:\Recovery\WindowsRE (or GUID)
mkdir R:\Recovery\WindowsRE
copy /y C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winre.wim (or guid folder) R:\Recovery\WindowsRE
```

If you skipped and it was in `R:\Recovery\WindowsRE` OR finished step 2 run:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\reagentc /setreimage /path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /target C:\Windows"

bcdedit /enum /v OSLOADER (to get bcd identifier)
should be the second one.
"C:\Windows\System32\reagentc /enable /osguid {72b4bd9d-59d1-11ee-8e50-8735f498fd7f}
```

**(example guid only!)**

You can do this inside Windows as well just without "target"
**may not be able to view Recovery folders in explorer, use CMD!**

Comment: can you clarify which is Step 2?